# Yahoo YQL get data using sql query for different stock exchanges

Tags: yahoo-finance

hot to get nasdaq, Dow Jones,S&P 500, Nikkei 300 from yahoo apl.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("^IXIC") not work.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use different tables for stock exchange...

You can use any of the 2 options below,

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quoteslist where symbol= '^IXIC'
```

OR

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quoteslist where symbol in ('^GSPC','^IXIC')
```