# "No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quoteslist" error when trying YQL

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I want to get quotes of nasdaq, Dow Jones,S&P 500 and Nikkei 300.

So as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688567/yahoo-yql-get-data-using-sql-query-for-different-stock-exchanges) suggested I type `select * from yahoo.finance.quoteslist where symbol in ('^GSPC','^IXIC')` in YQL Console. https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

Then I got the error `No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quoteslist`.

It looks like there is no table `yahoo.finance.quoteslist` neither `yahoo.finance.quotes`.
Are the tables no more available?

Is there a way that I can get equivalent values from Yahoo API?

Answer (score 0):

Those are both considered YQL Community Tables - data definitions that are written by others outside of Yahoo.

To use these tables, enable the checkbox in the upper left corner for Show Community Tables.

This link should bring up your example query in the YQL console with the `yahoo.finance.quoteslist` table working correctly:

[select * from yahoo.finance.quoteslist where symbol in ('^GSPC','^IXIC')](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quoteslist%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%27%5EGSPC%27%2C%27%5EIXIC%27%29&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)